# How Idmessage Get TextBody from openpgp encode message with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, imap, indy

content type is  Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="nm_5da15248d437196b097ad4ae2ba7"

how can i do with Inmessage to Get Text?

the correct way to check mail content

Answer (score 0):

`multipart/...` content is stored in separate `TIdText` and `TIdAttachment` objects in the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` property, it is not stored in the `TIdMessage.Body` property (unless `TIdMessage.NoDecode=True`, that is).

You will have to enumerate the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` looking for a `TIdMessagePart` object whose `ContentType` represents the data you want to process, and then you can type-cast that object to either `TIdText` or `TIdAttachment` based on whether its `PartType` is `mptText` or `mptAttachment`, and then you can handle that object's data as needed (ie, using the `TIdText.Body` property, or the `TIdAttachment.OpenLoadStream()` or `TIdAttachment.SaveTo...()` method).

Comment: is Indy support openpgp ?

Comment: Not directly, no. But you should be able to extract the raw encrypted data/signature/keys to use in any OpenPGP library you want.

Comment: ok...i use cis instead it just support